# Motorcycle ride to Malaysia from Singapore avoiding expressways

Tags: road-trips, routes, malaysia, singapore, motorcycles

I am planning to get a cruiser bike in Singapore and I have a valid Singapore license. I want to go visit the Malaysian towns and villages on my motorcycle. I want to do it **alone**. But I heard some part of the country is dangerous for riders because of theft. I have some places in mind like Malacca, Desaru, Kuala Lumpur, Cameron Highlands. My questions are.

1. Is it possible to travel Malaysia bypassing expressways. How safe it is? (The reason for this is to see the towns,people and the countryside. Last time when I go KL via the expressway in a car, the journey is too fast and I cant see anything other than the palm trees)
2. Are there any other good places to visit in Malaysia that can be reached in motorbike?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Malaysians love their *motosikal* and you can easily tour the country by bike without using expressways.  For example, for Johor Bahru to Kuala Lumpur, and even onward past Penang all the way to the Thai border, you can use the old National Highway 1.  (*Tip*: do a search in Google Maps, pop open "Show options", and choose "Avoid highways".  Here's [Singapore to KL](http://goo.gl/maps/rN6Cp).)

There are three main risks with driving in Malaysia:

- **Crazy drivers**.  Be extra cautious on country or mountain roads, and don't drive at night if you can help it.
- **Corrupt cops** stopping you for violations real or imagined, looking for an RM50 "on-the-spot fine".  Kind of unavoidable, and you'll be a target because of your Singapore plates, but not driving on the expressway will lower your profile.
- **Bike theft**.  Not really a problem in the countryside, but stick to guarded car parks in the cities, and tip the attendant.

And the best resource for all things Malaysian and motorcycley: [Malaysian Riders](http://malaysian-riders.com/).